# Negativity of Convex Combinations

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Consider the functions $f(x)$, $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ with following properties:

$\int f(x) dx =\int  g_1(x)dx =\int g_2(x)dx =1$.

Define the following measure of negativity for the functions:

$N[F(x)]:=\int  |F(x)|dx$,

which is similar to $l_1$-norm.
Accordingly, we have the following properties for three functions above:

$N[f(x)]=1 \Rightarrow$ It is positive,

$1\neq N[g_2(x)]>N[g_1(x)] \neq 1 \Rightarrow$ $g_2$ has more negaitivity that $g_1$.

Define the following convex combinations ($q\in [0,1]$):

$h_1(x):=(1-q) f(x)+ q g_1(x)$,

$h_2(x):=(1-q) f(x)+ q g_2(x)$.

Suppose that $\exists q^{(1)}_{\max}$ such that $\forall q\in[0,q^{(1)}_{\max}]:N[h_1(x)]=1$, that is, $q^{(1)}_{\max}$ is the largest value for which $h_1(x)$ is positive.

The same value can be found for $h_2$ as well, denoted by $q^{(2)}_{\max}$.

The Question is, How can I prove that $q^{(2)}_{\max}>q^{(1)}_{\max}$ given above conditions on $f,g_1$ and $g_2$?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples to show that the relative order of the $q^{(i)}_{\text{max}}$ isn't determined by the relative order of the $N(g_i)$.  All functions are $[0,1]\to\mathbb R$.
\begin{align*}
g_1(x) &= \begin{cases} 3 &\text{if $x<\tfrac12$,} \\ -1 &\text{if $x\ge\tfrac12$.} \end{cases} \\
g_2(x) &= \begin{cases} -2 &\text{if $x<\tfrac12$,} \\ 4 &\text{if $x\ge\tfrac12$.} \end{cases} \\
\end{align*}
Then $N(g_1) = 2 < 3 = N(g_2)$.  But if $f$ is
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 2 &\text{if $x<\tfrac12$,} \\ 0 &\text{if $x\ge\tfrac12$.} \end{cases} $$
then $q^{(1)}_{\text{max}} = 0 < q^{(2)}_{\text{max}}$, while if $f$ is
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if $x<\tfrac12$,} \\ 2 &\text{if $x\ge\tfrac12$.} \end{cases} $$
then $q^{(1)}_{\text{max}} > 0 = q^{(2)}_{\text{max}}$.

Comment: Thanks Steven. This helps a lot. Actually my space is not [0,1], however, this shows that due to subadditivity of N, presumably I can find a counter example in my case.